# largest factorial number present as a factor in some integer n

Tags: algorithm, factorial, factorization

I am working on designing an algorithm to find the largest factorial number present as a factor in some integer n. This problem is given in "How to solve it by computer" by R.G.Dormey. 
could you help me in how to go about designing algorithm.. answer has to be a factor of the integer n and also a factorial number..

solution I thought of:

first confirm that integer is not prime. if prime, no further solution posible..

if not prime, find out the largest factor of the integer

check if it is a factorial number or not..

if yes, that is the answer

if not, find out second largest factor of the integer..

check if it is a factorial number or not...

and so on..

Comment: What is the largest possible integer that you want to test ?

Comment: good point.. i didn't think of that.. I thought of using short int for the number.. so it would be 65535

Comment: In that case you only need a table of factorials up to `8! == 40320` and you can then test whether any of these divides exactly into your target number. Even with 32 bit unsigned ints you only need to go up to `12!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to find the largest factorial that goes into your integer, so you just need to steadily increase your factors.  I.e. Check to see if the resulting integer is divisible by 2, 3, 4, etc...  The first time you get a failure you know that no larger factorial will divide your integer.  E.g. if your integer is divisible by 2 ... 6 but not 7, you know the answer is 6!.

Comment: -1: If your integer is divisible by 2 ... 5 and not 6, you've got a rather strange number.  It's divisible by 2 and 3 but not by 6?  Seems to be the accepted answer, but this is just wrong!

Comment: that was just an example. method is absolutely right. it worked. this answer is same as Dennis's answer below.

Comment: The number 60 is divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, but not 7.  However, 6! is NOT the answer.

Comment: @Tom - Just to make this clear; in that case you'd say 60 is divisible by 2 to give 30, 30 is divisible by 3 to give 10, 10 is not divisible by 4 therefore 3! is the answer.

Comment: Yeah you're using the result of the previous division at each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Divide N by 1, then the result by 2, then the result by 3,... then by k+1. Once there is no integer result for k+1,  k! is an answer.

Comment: +1: This answer is correct.  Though I would say that k! is **the** answer.

Answer (score 0):

given the property of factorials to grow very very large very fast...i would be tempted to try dividing it directly.
first find the largest factorial less than your number...then start checking by dividing
eg: let N be your number. Let factorial f(fac,num) be your factorial function which returns a factorial less than your number. such that num! = fac
  Then do the following:

Check if (N % fac)==0; else try (N*num) % fac   then (N* (num)*(num-1)) % fac

the answer u require is (num) in first case (num-1) in second case and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
long prod = 1;
long maxFactor = 1;

for(long i=2; i<=n && prod< n && n%i==0 ;i++){

    prod  = prod*i;
    if(n%prod == 0) maxFactor = prod;
}
```

Here `n` is the number whose largest factorial factor we need to find out and the final value of macFactor is the final solution.

**Note:** Factors of factor of a number are also the factors of the number.

If the factor is a factorial value then it must the product of the consecutive integers starting from 1  (in other words it should be the product of its factors other than itself)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
      int i,n;
      scanf("%d",&n);
      for(i=2;n>1&&n%i==0;i++)
      n/=i;
      printf("%d",i-1);
}
```

n is the input number